# Can you force doctrine's querybuilder to not expect an operand in a where clause?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

In SQL it's possible to make a where statement that is true, without actually writing 'column = true'. Instead you can use 'column' and the query will then return all the rows where it's true.

As far as I can figure out, this isn't a possibility in doctrine's query builder and when I try anything similar, the following QueryException is thrown:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 428: Error: Expected =, &lt;, &lt;=, &lt;&gt;, &gt;, &gt;=, !=, got 'AND'
```

Are there any way to get around this issue? It has to be a solution involving the query builder.

Edit:

Here's the code in question:

```
$qb->andWhere("MBRContains(:linestring, location.position) = true")
```

which I would very much like to be:

```
$qb->andWhere("MBRContains(:linestring, location.position)")
```

The issue is that MBRContains doesn't use the spatial index in the first case. MBRContains is from a doctrine extension, but the issue could be simplified down to:

```
$qb->andWhere("account.email_validated")
```

which wouldn't work either.

Comment: Can you please show us your code to understand well?

Comment: Of course! It's now been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I found a solution, I figured I'd post it here, in case others should experience the same issue.

You're gonna need a custom SqlWalker, which you will have to apply to your query. Since I'm using the QueryBuilder, I had to get the query before I could apply the walker. Anyway here's the code:

```
$query = $qb->getQuery;
$query->setHint(Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, CustomSqlWalker::class);
$query->setHint(UseIndexWalker::HINT_REMOVE_EQUAL_TRUE, true);
```

With the SqlWalker looking like this:

```
<?php
namespace YOUR_NAME_SPACE;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

class CustomSqlWalker extends SqlWalker {
    const HINT_REMOVE_EQUAL_TRUE = 'CustomSqlWalker.RemoveEqualTrue';

    public function walkWhereClause($whereClause) {
        $result = parent::walkWhereClause($whereClause);

        if ($this->getQuery()->getHint(self::HINT_REMOVE_EQUAL_TRUE)) {
            $result = preg_replace('/= 1/', '', $result);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```